# Elements are getting overlapped when drag and dropped in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am facing issue while drag and drop in selenium . Actually i want elements to be dropped at different location but in my case all the elements are getting overlapped when dropped. I used all possible set of code using offset but ending up with same scenario.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

Actions action = new Actions(driver);

//1st method            
            actions.clickAndHold(circle).moveByOffset(555,575).build().perform();           
action.release(destination).build().perform();
actions.clickAndHold(rect).moveByOffset(726,598).build().perform();
action.release(destination).build().perform();*/


//2nd method

actions.clickAndHold(circle).moveToElement(destination,331,151).build().perform();
action.release(destination).build().perform();
            actions.clickAndHold(rect).moveToElement(destination,584,137).build().perform(); action.release(destination).build().perform();     actions.clickAndHold(src).moveToElement(destination,82,367).build().perform();
action.release(destination).build().perform();

//3rd method

actions.dragAndDropBy(circle, 331, 151);
actions.dragAndDropBy(rect, 584, 137);
actions.build().perform();

//4th method

actions.dragAndDrop(src, destination); 
actions.dragAndDrop(rect, destination);
```

actions.dragAndDrop(circle, destination);
actions.build().perform();

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this method:

```
(new Actions(Driver)).DragAndDropToOffset(element, xoffset, yoffset).Perform();
```